# create mysql event on button click, to delete the first row of table every 5 minutes?

Tags: php, mysql, events, onclick

Here is my php page which is called on button click.

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="parth"; // Database name



$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die('Could not connect to MySQL server: ' . mysql_error());
//echo"Connected to MySQL server";
mysql_select_db("parth") or die('Could not connect to database' . mysql_error());
//echo "Connected to Database";



$sql="CREATE EVENT gold ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 3 SECOND
DO
DELETE FROM table LIMIT 1;";
mysql_query($sql);
echo "done";
?>
```

the echo message "done" is displayed

But the event query does not get executed. I have given the privileges too.
Just used 3 SECOND for development purpose.

Comment: What does `mysql_query` return?

Comment: its definition query create event...May be errors if not executed

Comment: _What does mysql_query return?_ Please check that return code. Please use `mysql_error` if that return value is **false**.

Comment: the php documentation does not say about  the return type when create statement will be executed in mysql_query()..  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Can't use function return value in write context in the line where error_reporting(E_ALL)=mysql_query($sql); was declared

Comment: no errors are displayed when declared error_reporting(E_ALL) in beginning. Then added $results=mysql_query($sql); But then also nothing happens.

Comment: now its executing but the event query is executing only once and not recurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_All);
$sHost = "localhost";
$sUsername = "root";
$sPassword = "";
$sDb = "parth";

$con = mysql_connect($sHost, $sUsername, $sPassword) or die('Could not connect to MySQL server: ' . mysql_error());
echo"Connected to MySQL server";

mysql_select_db($sDb) or die('Could not connect to database' . mysql_error());
echo "Connected to Database";

$sResult = mysql_query("CREATE EVENT gold ON SCHEDULE EVERY 3 MINUTE STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 3 SECOND DO DELETE FROM table LIMIT 1;") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Done";
```

Comment: Thanx micha!! now its executing but the event query gest executed only once and its not recurring

Comment: @Parth mehta It's excuting only once because you used `AT` keywork, if you want make it execute every 3 minutes use `EVERY 3 MINUTE STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Check manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html