# MySQL query working in terminal but not working in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use the following MySQL query in my PHP code:

```
DELIMITER | 
CREATE EVENT event1
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
DO
BEGIN 
   UPDATE user SET access_flag = 0 WHERE user_id = 1;
   UPDATE user SET access_counter = 0 WHERE user_id = 1;
END;
| DELIMITER ;
```

Here's my PHP code:

```
$sql="DELIMITER | CREATE EVENT event$user_id
                    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
                    DO
                    BEGIN 
                    UPDATE user SET access_flag = 0 WHERE user_id = $user_id;
                    UPDATE user SET access_counter = 0 WHERE user_id = $user_id;
                    END;
                    | DELIMITER";
              if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
              die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
              }
```

And, this is the error I am getting:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER | CREATE EVENT event9 ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL' at line 1

Funny thing is that when I execute the query directly to MySQL in terminal or MySQL Workbrench it's working fine. What am I doing wrong?

Actually,I got it to work by eliminating multiple statements and used query like this:

```
CREATE EVENT event1
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
DO 
UPDATE user SET access_flag = 0,
access_counter = 0 WHERE user_id = 1;
```

Thanks for the tips. I still don't know why it wasn't working in the first place..

Comment: and $user_id variable is fine. You see in error that it has the value of 9 ...

Comment: Why two `UPDATE` queries? Only one is needed.

Comment: Did you try without DELIMITER?

Comment: You think I can do it like this: 
CREATE EVENT event1
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
DO
   UPDATE user SET access_flag = 0 WHERE user_id = 1
   SET access_counter = 0 WHERE user_id = 1;
If so. I didn't know. I'm new to MySQL

Comment: Try this: $sql="CREATE EVENT event$user_id
                    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
                    DO
                    BEGIN 
                    UPDATE user SET access_flag = 0 WHERE user_id = $user_id;
                    UPDATE user SET access_counter = 0 WHERE user_id = $user_id;
                    END;";

Comment: Look at what the error is telling you `right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER`

Comment: Note that you can create event only once ;)

Comment: Also as Mike W said you can use one update instead like: UPDATE user SET access_flag = 0, access_counter = 0 WHERE user_id = $user_id;

Comment: Without delimiter it isn't working even directly in MySQL...

Comment: Did you try in PHP. It is nomal it to not work in the console.

Comment: Try getting rid of just `DELIMITER |` and `| DELIMITER` - See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8552245/ as an example. Since that's where the syntax error is pointing, [`as I mentioned already`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069802/mysql-query-working-in-terminal-but-not-working-in-php#comment40845859_26069802).

Comment: @bksi didn't know that. That may actually work. Thx

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that with mysqli in php. The `DELIMITER` are statements by themselves, you might give it a try with `mysqli_multiquery` but even like this, I'm pretty sure it won't be supported.

Comment: *"I still don't know why it wasn't working in the first place"* - Read the **SQL error**. SQL didn't implement it in there *just cuz*. Why even post the error message in the first place if you're not going to bother with it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql="CREATE EVENT event$user_id 
       ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE 
         DO 
           BEGIN 
              UPDATE user SET access_flag = 0, access_counter = 0
              WHERE user_id = $user_id; 
           END;";
```

Note that DELIMITER is used in the console to change the original MySQL delimiter ";", so the query should not be broken. In PHP you don't need to change the delimiter. Also you can use one UPDATE when the table is same, just separate different states with ,
Also note that you can create EVENT only once.